# Gradle do something before "plugins id"

Tags: gradle

I want `apply from` run before `plugins id`, and `plugins` use variables from a remote file. However It doesn't works.

[common.gradle](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/caliburn1994/Spring-Data-REST-Demo/main/config/common.gradle):

```
ext {
    // test
    testcontainersVersion = "1.15.0"
    // spring
    springBootVersion = '2.4.2'
    springDependencyManagement = '1.0.10.RELEASE'
}
```

build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version "${springBootVersion}"
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version "${springDependencyManagement}"
    id 'java'
}

apply from: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/caliburn1994/Spring-Data-REST-Demo/main/config/common.gradle'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works with `buildscript` block.

```
buildscript {
    apply from: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/caliburn1994/Spring-Data-REST-Demo/main/config/common.gradle'
}

plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version "${springBootVersion}"
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version "${springDependencyManagement}"
    id 'java'
}
```